# Improve progress-bar view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout, android-progressbar

I have a progress bar, that I show to the user until loading is complete. It's good but there is a white rectangle in the middle of the layout, which I want to remove.

[image]

I want only the rotating ProgressBar in the middle of the layout.

How to remove this white rectangle?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
        android:paddingTop="5sp"
        android:paddingBottom="5sp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
        android:max="100"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and this the progress_bar drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="200"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadius="18dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="4dp"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="48dp"
            android:width="48dp" />

        <gradient
            android:centerColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:startColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:centerY="0.5"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: It looks like that rectangle might be part of your "@drawable/progress_bar". Can you provide that?

Comment: @BenjaminBasmaci I've updated the question

Comment: Just copy-pasted your code into my project. No white rectangle visible. Are you sure the progress bar itself is causing it? Can you provide more of the original code?

Comment: A screenshot pls?

Comment: https://imgur.com/MUqJFl0